# How to insert large XML string into an Oracle Table?

Tags: string, oracle, xmltype

I want to insert a large XML string into my Table. My table is test_id(xml_column XMLType).

When I insert the values, it returns 'string literal too long' error. I surf on the net about this, everyone says to change the datatype to CLOB. But i want to store the same datatype(XMLType).

Is there any possibilities to do that. Can anyone help me to fix this.

Here is my code:

```
insert into TEST_ID(xml_column) values('<root>
  <DatabaseLog>
    <DatabaseLogID>1</DatabaseLogID>
    <PostTime>2012-03-14T13:14:18.803</PostTime>
...
<object>StoreSurveySchemaCollection</object>
  </DatabaseLog>
</root>');
```

The error code is:

```
PLS-00172: string literal too long
```

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Oracle 11g, the maximum size for an `XMLTYPE` value is 2G/4G depending your character set. This is the same as the `CLOB` type. But, the issue here is not with the *content* being too large for the `XMLTYPE`. It is the *litteral* `VARCHAR` you use in your query that is too long. The error message is quite clear with that matter:

> PLS-00172: string literal too long

A solution (not a very elegant one though) is to break your string is several pieces, assigning to a `CLOB` variable:

```
xmlDoc CLOB := 'xml chunk #1';
...
xmlDoc := xmlDoc || 'xml chunk #2';
xmlDoc := xmlDoc || 'xml chunk #3';

...
insert into TEST_ID(xml_column) values(xmlDoc);
```

Comment: You can use yourXML.GETCLOBVAL() to get a CLOB from an xmltype.

Comment: Sylvain, How can we make this operation dynamically when we don't know size of the json string and want to insert in XMLTYPE?