# Inserting large XML document into Oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have a table in Oracle:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (id NUMBER, document XMLType)
```

and I would typically insert data into it with SQL:

```sql
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, XMLType('<parent><child></child></parent>'))
```

However, I now have a document which is more than the maximum size for a string literal in PL/SQL (4000 characters). Is it possible to insert such a document in a single SQL script, without resorting to writing it to a file and then referencing that file in the sql... as that option is not open to us for reasons. I have tried:

- inserting 4000 characters, then appending the rest in chunks - this does not work as the intermediate steps fail XML validation
- temporarily changing the column type to `CLOB` etc. - Oracle forbids the conversion of columns between major types.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert large XML string into an Oracle Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27601085/how-to-insert-large-xml-string-into-an-oracle-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL, concatenate 4000 byte strings to `EMPTY_CLOB()`:

```sql
INSERT INTO foo (id, document)
VALUES (1, XMLTYPE(
  EMPTY_CLOB()
  || 'first 4000 bytes...'
  || 'second 4000 bytes...'
  || 'etc.'
));
```

In PL/SQL, the limit for strings is 32,000 bytes:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_id  NUMBER := 1;
  v_xml VARCHAR2(32000) := 'your 32k XML string';
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO foo(id, document) VALUES (v_id, XMLTYPE(v_xml));
END;
/
```

Otherwise, you can use the same technique as the SQL answer in PL/SQL:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_id  NUMBER := 1;
  v_xml CLOB := EMPTY_CLOB()
                || 'first 32k XML string'
                || 'second 32k XML string'
                || 'etc.';
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO foo(id, document) VALUES (v_id, XMLTYPE(v_xml));
END;
/
```

Comment: I tried this, and it produces a script which looks correct but my dockerised Oracle instance segfaults on it... :(

Comment: @JuliaHayward All the options work in an Oracle 18 database [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=37fc164c09975bdc80414e74440415d2). Are you using an old database version?

Comment: Yes, 12.1.0.2. Sadly I'm constrained to that version.

Comment: @JuliaHayward The final option works in Oracle 11gR2 [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=37fc164c09975bdc80414e74440415d2). It should work on Oracle 12r1 (but I don't have that version so cannot test it).